# Iframes e Fancybox

Tags: iframe, fancybox

Estou querendo abrir um *iframe* do Google Maps em uma Fancybox via `fancybox.iframe`.
Porém dá o seguinte erro:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Eu sei da explicação sobre alguma coisa de *cross-domain* e que o ajax não faz isso mas, existe alguma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Coloque isso no seu .htaccess para liberar a busca externa a qualquer site:

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(*)$">
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

ou somente para o maps:

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(*)$">
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://maps.google.com
      </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```